# Postgres JDBC Using LIKE

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a simple test like this:

```
public Connection connect(String url, String user, String port, String password, String database) {
      debug("Try to connect at " + user+"@"+url+":"+port+"/"+database); 
      Connection connection = null;
      try {
         Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
         connection= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://"+url+":"+port+"/"+database, user, password);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         error(e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
      }
      debug("Database Connected."); 
      return connection;
}


public boolean executeSql( Connection connection, String sql ) {
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        stmt.close();
        connection.close();
        return true;
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        error( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );
        return false;
    }
}
```

and try to run a query with this content:

```
( awk_out.optifunc like '%omega%' or awk_out.optifunc like '%chi%' or awk_out.optifunc like '%SIZE%' or awk_out.optifunc like '%d!_%' ESCAPE '!' )
```

But I'm getting this error:

`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "%"`

How can I run queries with "%" character without using prepared statements?
Note: I can't use nothing but what I've put here ( no hibernate, no prepared statements... )

**EDIT:** Complete query ( and now I can see the error !!! )
The %ID_PIP% tag was not replaced before submit to the SQL engine.

```
insert into select_geni_out (id_instance, id_experiment, id_activity, 
adjacency, laplacian, slaplacian, adjacencyB, laplacianB, slaplacianB,
 optifunc, caixa1, gorder, mindegree, maxdegree, trianglefree, allowdiscgraphs,
 biptonly, g6file, g6fileid, g6splitedfile, maxresults, chromatic, chromaticb,
 click, clickb, largestdegree, numedges) select %ID_PIP%, 260, 2857, 
awk_out.adjacency,awk_out.laplacian, awk_out.slaplacian, awk_out.adjacencyb, 
awk_out.laplacianb, awk_out.slaplacianb, awk_out.optifunc, awk_out.caixa1, 
awk_out.gorder, awk_out.mindegree, awk_out.maxdegree, awk_out.trianglefree, 
awk_out.allowdiscgraphs, awk_out.biptonly, awk_out.g6file, awk_out.g6fileid, 
awk_out.g6splitedfile, awk_out.maxresults, awk_out.chromatic, 
awk_out.chromaticb, awk_out.click, awk_out.clickb, awk_out.largestdegree 
,awk_out.numedges from awk_out where awk_out.id_experiment =  260 and ( 
awk_out.optifunc like '%omega%' or awk_out.optifunc like '%chi%' or 
awk_out.optifunc like '%SIZE%' or awk_out.optifunc like '%d!_%' ESCAPE '!' )
```

Comment: could you share your entire query please?

Comment: If it's going to be this "raw", have you tried to run the query in, for example, PgAdmin?  Since you're unable to use prepared statements you should be able to generate the string and run it pretty much as is.

Comment: Yes. The query is user customized and generated at runtime. It's running fine in PGAdminIII. I'll post the complete query but the error is because this char (%).

Comment: My fault guys.. I forgot to replace a tag in my query template: `...select %ID_PIP%, 260, 2857, awk_out...` The `%ID_PIP%` must be replaced before submit to the engine. Sorry and thanks. Cold case.